# How to color a certain part of an image in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an image like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy80N.jpg)
and when I set the bool chest to true, I want the guys chest in the image to be colored in blue or a similar color. How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use separate images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any way to color parts of this image dynamically. but the solution is that provide the images that you need when some actions happen and use them instead.
for example use an image with colored chest, when something happened about chest and you need to show that colored one.

happy coding...